# Why useState in React Hook not update state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When i try example from React Hook, i get a problem about `useState`.

In code below, when click button, i add event for `document` and check value of `count`.
My expect is get `count` in `console.log` and view as the same. But actual, i got old value (init value) in `console` & new value in view . I can not understand why `count` in view changed and `count` in callback of event not change.

One more thing, when i use `setCount(10);` (fix a number). And click button many time (>2), then click outside, i got only 2 log from `checkCount`. Is it React watch `count` not change then don't `addEventListener` in next time.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const add = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log("value set is ", count);
    document.addEventListener("click", checkCount);
  };

  const checkCount = () => {
    console.log(count);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <p>Click button first then click outside button and see console</p>
      <button onClick={() => add()}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-bose-vrcuo

Comment: Yes, React does check if `count` has changed and only rerenders if it has.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman  I wound't say works fine, there is a pretty serious bug here, event memory leak..

Comment: Could I ask, what is it your trying to do.  You currently have a pretty serious memory leak here, every time you click that button your adding another event listener to the DOM,.  you then never remove such events.  Normally events like this can be attached / detached inside the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Why are you adding and event listener on an event click?

Comment: @Keith Gotcha...

Comment: @Keith It not all code, this is small example from this . I have a component write by state full component and move it to state less component with hook. It is a component click outside, but i only add event when "Item" was clicked and i check state of it by state to do remove event. There are many item use ClickOutside component in same a screen then i don't want add event when render. More detail, i want make file manager with right click, left click, and doing handle with clickoutside. Now it's working with ClassComponent. Are u want to see this code to do help me convert it ? :3

Comment: @Dupocas i am doing handle clickoutside. And i want when click a item then add event, and use state in this component to do remove event. i don't want add when render it. This code below is small sample.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman yes, this code working but result does not like  my expected

Comment: In that case, what you want to do is have a `useState` with a `useEffect`, basically use state to determine if your capturing events, and use the `useEffect` hook to add & remove the events.  A simple boolean `capture` inside your state will do this.  I could knock up a quick snippet to show this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture events outside of your component using document.addEventListener, you will want to use the `useEffect` hook to add the event, you can then use the `useState` to determine if your capturing or not.

Notice in the `useEffect` I'm passing `[capture]`, this will make it so the useEffect will get called when this changes, a simple check for this capture boolean determines if we add the event or not.

By using useEffect, we also avoid any memory leaks, this also copes with when your unmount the component, it knows to remove the event too.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;


function Test() {
  const [capture, setCapture] = useState(false);
  const [clickInfo, setClickInfo] = useState("Not yet");
  
  function outsideClick() {
    setClickInfo(Date.now().toString());
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (capture) {
      document.addEventListener("click", outsideClick);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("click", outsideClick);
      }
    }
  }, [capture]);
  
  return <div>
    <p>
    Click start capture, then click anywhere, and then click stop capture, and click anywhere.</p>
    <p>{capture ? "Capturing" : "Not capturing"}</p>
    <p>Clicked outside: {clickInfo}</p>
    <button onClick={() => setCapture(true)}>
      Start Capture
     </button>
    <button onClick={() => setCapture(false)}>
      Stop Capture
    </button>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
  <Test/>
</React.Fragment>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```css
p { user-select: none }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: i understand your example but can't apply my code with hook. I have a answer about code in below. Can you support me ?

Answer (score 0):

@Keith i understand your example but when i apply get some confuse. In origin, i always call function is `handleClick` and still call it after run `handleClickOutside` but now i don't know how to apply that with hook.

This is my code that i want insted of Hook

```
class ClickOutSide extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.wrapperRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      active: false
    }
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    if(!this.state.active) {
      document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOut);
      document.addEventListener("contextmenu", this.handleClickOut);
      this.props.clickInside();
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOut);
      document.removeEventListener("contextmenu", this.handleClickOut);

    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      active: !prevState.active,
   }));
  };

  handleClickOut = event => {
    const { target } = event;
    if (!this.wrapperRef.current.contains(target)) {
      this.props.clickOutside();
    }

    this.handleClick()
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div
        onDoubleClick={this.props.onDoubleClick}
        onContextMenu={this.handleClick}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        ref={this.wrapperRef}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ClickOutSide
```